# wordpress url rewrite Query Var to Static url

Tags: url-rewriting, endpoints

i have urls like these:

```
http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/
```

and have some url parameters

```
http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/?chp=1
http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/?chp=2
http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/?chp=3
....
```

is there anyway to have urls like these:

```
http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/chp-*/
```

---

I found my solution: here is my code:

```
    add_action('init','mangareader_init');
    function mangareader_init() {
      global
      $wp,$wp_rewrite;
      $wp->add_query_var('chp');
      $wp_rewrite->add_rule('manga/([^/]+)/c([^/]+)',
        'index.php?post_type=manga&name=$matches[1]&chp=$matches[2]', 'top');
      // Once you get working, remove this next line
      //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  
    }
```

Comment: There are many examples of url rewriting out there and on here. What have you tried?

Comment: most of examples i found are like http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/chp/1 but i need a dynamic http://animup.net/manga/bara-no-maria/chp-*/

Comment: As mentioned by Waldermort many options available. I tried to check your site but stranded after being spammed by  advertisements as soon I clicked a nav tab.(Can't read your language, sorry. And oh my what a spamm ads you have/use) Anyway are those queries (meaning the ?chp=1)/output of some cache plugin you use, if so try to disable it and do refresh and see if it changed some by itself.

Comment: charles, i don't yet program "chp" query var but it's easy and i have some registered query var. i know i hate pop up ads but i'm dedicated server and need more money, i checked alot of questions here but i couldn't find relevant question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets try this (didn't want to put it "just as comment" because of the code.

In your comment you gave still no answer on a "possible caching issue" but still. Maybe, just maybe this part of code in .htaccess could help. Be aware this code could mess up more then wished! *(Please read what is explained! follow that link for more information please).*

This code before the line # BEGIN Wordpress in .htaccess. Source code found [here](http://briancray.com/posts/htaccess-hack-remove-url-query-strings/).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""         #if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*       #wordpress users: allow post tempalinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.* #wordpress users: don't break admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]        #remove query string
```

I also found some answers on Stackoverflow itself. Maybe there you also find some source code you could use/try. [RewriteCond/RewriteRule for removing query strings from URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260989/formatting-htaccess-rewritecond-rewriterule-for-removing-query-string-from-ur)

Another answer which maybe could help is found here: [also stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)